# Google chrome uses wrong keyboard input method

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-layout, 21.10

I installed a fresh Ubuntu 21.10 and then installed `google-chrome-stable` from http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/. I am using norwegian keyboard layout, so when pressing SHIFT and the key above Ctrl on the right side of the spacebar it should give a colon `:`, but in `google-chrome` it gives a larger than symbol `>` (I think this is the american keyboard layout?). Here is a screenshot where I type into the search bar in Google Chrome:

[image]

In firefox it works fine, and I get the `:` as I would expect:

[image]

I had no such problem with Ubuntu 21.04 (where I installed google-chrome the same way)

Comment: Have you made sure that Chrome is using the correct language?

Comment: I did not know I needed to do that? Since I did not do anything like that in Ubuntu 21.04 and it worked out of the box. How do I make sure Chrome is using the correct language?

Comment: 3 dots upper right corner + settings + advanced you will see the option.

Comment: I tried it, but it does not seem to affect the input method. It is only for spell checking and translation right?

Comment: Straight from the Chrome online help. https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/173424?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop

Comment: I tried the Google Input Tools Chrome extension, but it is only for translating text to a different language (and it does not even apply to the search bar). It does not affect the keyboard layout used

Comment: Added a similar question to Google Chrome community forum: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/131070494/google-chrome-uses-wrong-keyboard-input-method-on-ubuntu-21-10

Comment: Which desktop environment do you have, and how exactly did you add the Norwegian layout? Please edit your question and include that info.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I added the Norwegian layout when I installed Ubuntu 21.10 from the USB-stick. It is one the first screens in the installer, and it asks you to select keyboard layout. What do you mean by "desktop environment" ?

Comment: @HåkonHægland: I mean if it's standard Ubuntu (with GNOME) or one of the flavors.

Comment: @HåkonHægland: Assuming it's standard Ubuntu, kan you please go to Settings -> Keyboard, add some other layout — suggestion: English (US) — and then switch to English (US) and back to Norwegian. Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

If you have set English or something else as a second language in Google Chrome (Settings -> Advanced -> Languages), try removing it and restart Chrome (!). That fixed the issue for me. I then added English back and it still works.

(At the same time, I updated Chrome to 96.0.4664.93, maybe that helped, too.)

Solution from https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/onj4t0/kde_on_wayland_changes_the_keyboard_layout_cf_kde/